# object position is added in qs.stringify result express nodejs querystring

Tags: javascript, node.js, query-string

I have an object which I'm trying to stringify w/ qs npm library:

```
var obj = [{"product":7001,"quantity":1},{"product1":3002,"quantity1":1},{"product2":4001,"quantity2":1},{"product3":3004,"quantity3":1}]
```

when I stringify I'm getting result with the index:

```
var str = qs.stringify(obj);

//result (not encoded
0[product]=7001&0[quantity]=1&1[product]=3002&1[quantity]=1&2[product]=4001&2[quantity]=1

// result encoded
    0%5Bproduct%5D=7001&0%5Bquantity%5D=1&1%5Bproduct1%5D=3002&1%5Bquantity1%5D=1&2%5Bproduct2%5D=4001&2%5Bquantity2%5D=1
```

Is this because the keys names are unique ? I need to pass this object to a callback and this would be ideal:

```
product=7001&quantity=1&product1=3002&quantity1=1&product2=4001&quantity2=1
```

btw my object format is odd yes its a legacy api. thank you for any advice.

Comment: qs doesn't do this, you'll need to write your own logic to support this approach.

Comment: thanks, I was able to reduce the obj like so:

---

`var myObj = _.reduce( obj, function( memo, item ) {
      return _.extend( memo, item ); }, {} );

  var myStrObj = qs.stringify(myObj);
  console.log('querystring:  ' + JSON.stringify(myStrObj));
`

Answer (score 0):

format obj, and then use `qs` library

```
var obj = [{ "product": 7001, "quantity": 1 }, { "product1": 3002, "quantity1": 1 }, { "product2": 4001, "quantity2": 1 }, { "product3": 3004, "quantity3": 1 }]

var formatObj = Object.assign.apply(null, obj);
var str = qs.stringify(formatObj);
console.log(str);
```